# como gravar dados no firebase com ionic?

Tags: ionic, firebase

eu tenho uma aplicaçao que exibe na tela a latitude e a longitude queria saber como gravar esses dados no firebase

meu codigo home.ts ta assim

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation, GeolocationOptions, Geoposition} from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage{

```
geoposition: Geoposition

geolocationOptions: GeolocationOptions
    constructor(private platform: Platform, 
        private geolocation: Geolocation,
        public navCtrl: NavController){
        }

    async getGeolocation(){
        await this.platform.ready();

        try {

            this.geolocationOptions = {
                maximumAge: 1000,
                timeout: 1000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            }

            this.geoposition = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geolocationOptions);
        }
        catch(e){
            console.error(e)
        }

    }
```

}

o html que exibe na tela os dados

```
 <ion-list>
                        <ion-item>
                            Accurary: {{geoposition.coords.accuracy}}
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            Latitude: {{geoposition.coords.latitude}}
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            Longitude: {{geoposition.coords.longitude}}
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            Timestamp:{{geoposition.timestamp |date}}
                        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

a utilização do Firebase no Ionic pode ser realizada utilizando o Angular.

Segue um tutorial super bacana para implementar um crud com AngularFire2

https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-4-firebase-crud-operations-with-angularfire2-v4